# Keras array shape error

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

How come I am getting a shape `ValueError` for my neural network when what I am passing in is an array of shape `(8,1)` but the error I am getting is that the neural network is complaining about getting a `(1,)`?

Neural Network:

```
>>> observation_dimension
(8,)
>>> q_network = Sequential([
    Dense(40, input_dim=observation_dimension, activation='relu'),
    Dense(40, activation='relu'),
    Dense(number_of_actions, activation='linear')
])
>>> obs
array([-0.00371828,  0.93953934, -0.37663383, -0.07161933,  0.00431531,
        0.08531308,  0.        ,  0.        ])
>>> obs.shape
(8,)
```

Error:

```
>>> q_network.predict(obs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
...
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_27_input to have shape (8,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model.predict` takes a batch of samples, if you give it a single sample with the wrong shape, it will interpret the first dimension as the batch one.

A simple solution is to add a dimension with a value of one:

```
q_network.predict(obs.reshape(1, 8))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `predict` method expects a 2d array so just reshape your `obs`:

```
obs = np.reshape(obs,(-1,len(obs)))
```